# DialogResult.OK Не работает. WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void ButtonPath(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = "";
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filePath = ofd.FileName;
        MessageBox.Show(filePath);
    }
}
```

Почему то выдает ошибку:

Ошибка  CS1061  "bool?" не содержит определения "OK", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "OK", принимающий тип "bool?" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)

Помогите пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `ShowDialog` объекта `OpenFileDialog` в Вашем случае возвращает `Nullable<bool>`. Подробнее [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8)

Сделайте проверку на результат вывода диалога, а не на `enum`. Ну или cast.